# javascript using a div created in script with plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a div using jquery and put some text in it:

```
        var newdiv=$('<div id="content">').append('some text here');
        $("#wrapper").append(newdiv);
```

Now I am trying to use the plugin masonry on the div.

I have added the following just below the above that creates the div:

```
$("#wrapper").masonry();
```

I have checked and jquery and masonry are loading correctly.

The new div called content shows in firebug correctly, but the masonry part is not doing anything to the new "content" div.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have other div's in there? What exactly do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should try adding 'appended':

```
var newdiv=$('<div id="content">').append('some text here');
$("#wrapper").append(newdiv);
$("#wrapper").masonry('appended', newdiv);
```

There's an append/prepend example here http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html

Comment: Thanks I had missed that example